# R: Split Data Frame, then perform for:each functions (sorting) on each split

Tags: r, sorting, date, plyr

I have a data frame that contains options information for each date. Each date has multiple rows corresponding to a changing range of strike prices:

```
head(df)
       Date C/P   K      Vol     Delta       ID
1 01/23/1997   0 805 0.155814  0.234181 10007288
2 01/23/1997   1 790 0.159603 -0.609276 10333499
3 01/23/1997   0 815 0.141776  0.132414 10106825 
4 01/23/1997   1 700 0.257233 -0.060976 10012499
5 01/23/1997   1 680 0.279465 -0.035616 10072595
6 01/23/1997   0 730 0.197782  0.888286 10307920
```

I have 216 dates, and each date has 100-300 rows, one for each strike price. I want to split the data frame by date, and for each date frame, use C/P as primary sort key and K as secondary sort key.

Is plyr the package to use? I've tried split(df, df$Date) but I cannot find any documentation on applying a sorting function to each split data frame.

By primary and secondary sort, I mean:

```
Input:
C/P K   Vol Delta
0   800 0.1 0.11
1   800 0.2 0.22
1   700 0.3 0.33
0   700 0.4 0.44
1   900 0.5 0.55
1   600 0.6 0.66
0   600 0.7 0.77
0   900 0.8 0.88

Output:
C/P K   Vol Delta
0   600 0.7 0.77
0   700 0.4 0.44
0   800 0.1 0.11
0   900 0.8 0.88
1   600 0.6 0.66
1   700 0.3 0.33
1   800 0.2 0.22
1   900 0.5 0.55
```

Comment: You can use `lapply(split(df, df$Date), function(x) x[order(x[["C/P"]], x[["K"]]),])`  It would have been more informative, if you showed the expected output.   BTW, you don't need to `split` the dataset.  This can be done more easily with `data.table/dplyr` i.e.`setDT(df)[order("C/P", K), .SD, by = Date]`  The `C/P` column name is somewhat problematic.

Comment: something like `df[order(df$Date,df$'C/P'),]` ?

Comment: Please use the expected output that you will get from the example showed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` elements from the `split` output and then `order` the rows with "C/P" and "K" column values

```
lapply(split(df, df$Date), function(x) 
            x[order(x[["C/P"]], x[["K"]]),])
```

---

Or instead of the `split` method, any of the group by operations can be done.  With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Date', we `order` the "C/P" and "K" columns in 'i' and get the `Subset of Data.table`

```
setDT(df)[order(eval(as.name("C/P")), K), .SD, by = Date]
```

This may be useful if we are grouping by "Date", `order` based on columns and doing some operations on the rest of the columns.